# Using spring:message to define form tag attribute in Spring web application

Tags: java, xml, spring, forms, web-applications

I'm developing a Java/Spring web application. The problem I'm currently facing is that I'd like to have message from message.resources shown as an attribute in an HTML.

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="login" />
```

So instead of the hardcoded value "login" I need to the value of

`<spring:message code="general.submit" />` as the value attribute of that input tag. As the pages are all xml, it's no option to nest tags like

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="<spring:message code="general.submit" />" />
```

as it does not compile. I could, of course, read the value in the Java controller and use a JSTL variable to display the value, but I think it would be too hackish and complicated, especially for pages with large amount of submit buttons. Is there some kind of elegant way of accomplishing what I want to do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `<spring:message>` to store the value in a var, then reference that var using EL, e.g.

```
<spring:message code="general.submit" var="submitText"/>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="${submitText}" />
```