# It is possible to submit a hidden input by clicking on <spring:message>?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, submit

I thinked somthing like this, but I dont want to use a button to submit, I would submit by clicking on spring message. Is this possible somehow?

```
  <spring:url value="/admin/messages" var="messagesUrl" htmlEscape="true"/> 
    <form action="${messagesUrl}" method="POST" class="new-message">
        <input type="hidden" name="messageFromDashboard" value="true">
        <spring:message code="${newMessage}">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"></spring:message>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560305/using-springmessage-to-define-form-tag-attribute-in-spring-web-application) will be helpful. Why you don't want to use submit button? If you just wanted to look it like a label/link just use css similar to http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/5vHGc/

Html:

```
<button> your button that looks like a link</button>
```

Css:

```
button {
    background:none!important;
     border:none; 
     padding:0!important;

    /*optional*/
    font-family:arial,sans-serif; /*input has OS specific font-family*/
     color:#069;
     text-decoration:underline;
     cursor:pointer;
}
```